# Error while try to push docker image to private repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry

When i try to push an docker image, i receive the following message.

This may be because internal files in the layer store were modified. Re-pulling or rebuilding this image may resolve the issue

```html
2e12e39dbc83: Pushing [==================================================>] 110.6 MB
52a118051ff2: Already exists 
fd00846d8a3a: Already exists 
9f14db3a9fd9: Already exists 
d8933699c403: Already exists 
Failed to upload layer: Put https://privaterepo/v1/images/fc05a48f11d077de64302033d8cba3384873df2bd3084a1211f24b726a59d224/layer: could not verify layer data for: sha256:2e12e39dbc83fcfacfff9c522ea8709021dca87764ff32fc27218d1fd828796c. This may be because internal files in the layer store were modified. Re-pulling or rebuilding this image may resolve the issue
```

Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: You have just posted the error not the code. Or am I wrong?

Comment: in this cenario i have just an image tagged local. 
`
docker push dockerimagename:dockerimageversion
`

Comment: Is your private registry up and running?

Comment: Yes, for example, i could pull images from this repo without any problem.

Comment: When i curl this fslayer printed in this message i get the following result
[GET]
https://privaterepo/v1/images/fc05a48f11d077de64302033d8cba3384873df2bd3084a1211f24b726a59d224/layer

{"error": "Image is being uploaded, retry later"}

Comment: try to pull it first, rebuild it and then pushing it brack.

Answer (score -2):

I workaround this problem pushing same image with diferent tag name. But it sound like pretty strange...

If anyone has some explanation, i'll be gladdy to hear :)